# How to pass current recordId to Lightning Web Components(Quick Action) for target lightning__RecordAction and actionType ScreenAction

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, lightning-quickaction, summer-21

have a component like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
   <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
   <isExposed>true</isExposed>
   <targets>
       <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
   </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
   <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordAction">
     <actionType>ScreenAction</actionType>
   </targetConfig>
 </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

I need the record Id from which record page this action is fired, able to access it in `<actionType> Action </actionType>` but have to use recordId in `<actionType> ScreenAction </actionType>`

JS file is like,

```
import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";
 
declare default class Simple extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;

    connectedCallback() {
        console.log('===============');
        console.log(this.recordId);
        console.log('===============');
    }

    renderedCallback() {
        console.log('------------');
        console.log(this.recordId);
        console.log('------------');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/347055/is-recordid-passed-to-lwc-in-a-quick-action/347058?noredirect=1#comment508705_347058) as well that also confirmed my testing.

Using `recordId` in your html template will show the value in the 2nd `renderedCallback` once the Id is provided. You can add a conditional to allow the template to only show once there's a value in `recordId` as you presumably are doing some logic related to the record the action is called from:

```
<template>
    <template if:true={recordId}>
        <!-- Do whatever you want to do -->
    </template>
</template>
```

Comment: Yes, it is available in the 2nd renderedCallback, will have to do other restructuring according to functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the solution that was it! Spent the whole night trying to figure it out.