# Getting different recordId in account record detail page

Tags: lightning-web-components, quickaction

I am trying to place a LWC component in quick action and trying to do some logic depends on the record ID and I am getting the record ID like this inside LWC

```
 @api recordId;
```

and my account record detail page URL is

```
....devbox.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Account/0012F00000pT6aoQAC/view
```

when I place component like this outside of Highlights panel , I am getting correct record ID

[image]

```
recordId Outside:>>  0012F00000pT6aoQAC
```

but when I place it inside Highlight panel like this
[image]

I am getting recordID as undefined

```
recordId Inside:>>  undefined
```

How to pass correct record ID inside Highlights panel?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/347055/is-recordid-passed-to-lwc-in-a-quick-action/347058?noredirect=1#comment508705_347058. This link helped me to get the answer

Comment: record actions are headless so you it wont set record ID in your connected callback, rather call 
@api invoke(){} to check your record ID