# "List has no rows for assignment to SObject"

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning, soql, attachment

I create headless quick action "Generate and attach pdf". But when i click on my action i have error "List has no rows for assignment to SObject". What is my problem?

Error
[image]

How i can fix it?

Comment: Looks like you are passing in a blank recordid to me. The Opportunity query then returns no rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be probably due to the fact that `recordId` is undefined in `connectedCallback()` as I can see the value logged in console is `undefined`. When using headless quick actions, implement `invoke()` method to read the `recordId` and then trigger any Apex controller actions. You can find more details [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_quick_actions_headless).
Thanks !

Comment: It's strange, for some reason I can't add Invoke here. https://imgur.com/a/FAkSgvg

Comment: You can't define connectedCallback() inside invoke(). Consider moving the code from connectedCallback() to invoke() method. :)

Comment: thanks,, this removed the error, but for some reason Attachment still does not appear, it only works in Debug execute, when I click on Quick Action nothing happens, please watch the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmMLaPeHpls

Comment: Seems like a common issue, `getContentAsPdf()` doesn't work in lightning context. It fails silently. Workaround is you can replace `getContentAsPdf()` with `getContent()` and fill the attachment record field `ContentType` with value as `application/pdf`

Comment: you're right! thank you! You helped me a lot. I had another little problem in that I just had ScreenAction, you can read about that here if you are interested. thank you again https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/347055/is-recordid-passed-to-lwc-in-a-quick-action